# The Best way to create methods that receives parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'd like to know wich way is the best one to create methods that receives a low ammount of `parameters` like 1 or 2.

First One: Passing an entity class object as parameter.

```
MyClass entity = new MyClass();
BDClass bd = new BDClass();
entity.Name = "Alan";
bd.InsertName(entity);

public void InsertName(MyClass entity)
{
     ///A simple Insert/Select
}
```

Second One: Even programming on OO, use variables as parameter, instead of the entity class.

```
BDClass bd = new BDClass();
string name = "Alan";
bd.InsertName(name);  

public void InsertName(string name)
{
  ///A simple Insert/Select
}
```

I'd like to know wich one is the best considering performance and good practice of programming. Or it depends of the situation ? I Mean, I guess it's better to use entity class as parameter only when it's a big amount of class, and the variable with low quantity of parameter.

I know its nothing to do with codes itselves, but I just want to learn wich one is the Correctly way to programm

Comment: `InsertName(MyClass entity)` sound a little bit confusing. If you insert **names** why do you need the whole entity passed in?

Comment: I think the real question here is **what does `InsertName` do?**

Comment: This is always going to be subjective and down to personal preference. For a single parameter (`string name`) it seems fairly clear that `string name` is more "obvious" - but as the number of parameters grows the object approach becomes tempting... but where is the line, exactly? who can say

Comment: I just want to know wich one is the best, wich one will not overload my application... Why the downvotes? I've seen a lot of questions asking the best way to programming, even having nothing to do with codes, it got upvotes... Why the downvotes now ? I specified on my question that it had nothing to do with code, its about the best way to programm, why the question @MichaelPerrenoud ? -.-"

Comment: the downvotes aren't because of the question it's because you won't tell us what's the purpose of 'InsertName'.

Comment: I just want to know if there is or there isn't a huge difference of performance with both methods @IlyaIvanov?

Comment: I would always use the 2nd because it's obvious reading the method signature what it does (inserting the name passed as parameter to the object where this method is called on). Even if MyClass is big i would rather write bd.InsertName(entity.Name);

Comment: @ISun I didn't tell it because it doesnt matter !! And the name of the method, it's just a simple insert. The point of the questions is, Wich way is the best one when passing low ammount of parameters... Like 1 or 2. If there is a difference when it comes to performance.

Comment: @Ghaleon, I think you emphatically misunderstand the process of determining *what's best*. It's not black and white. You have understand the process as a whole. Based on what you've provided (which is effectively no information), it wouldn't matter which one you used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no big differences and a **correct** answer. Since you can write it in the 2nd form, and the method name is `InsertName`, I prefer the 2nd one.

Why? First, it needs only a name(string), otherwise only one parameter is not enough. Second, you can pass any name to it no matter it comes from `MyClass` or anywhere else.

If you really need to pass the `MyClass` object with a given type, it must be the case that you need more than just a name from it, where you can't replace with only passing a name string. And in that case, `MyClass` may be a dependency of `BDClass`.

Comment: I understand now. Really thanks. I'll use string instead the entity class now, and leave the entity class when I need more values (like 5+).

Comment: I think it's OK and future proof. You can start with a simple signature and refactor it later.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on situation which you are handling. If your about to add whole object of entity class and your method is written in some c# Library project and you want to use that method in other project where your collecting whole information about that object of Entity Than first method approach suits you... But at the end it is completely up to you what you want to do.

Comment: So there is not a huge difference of performance ?

Comment: Not really. If your going to add,update only a single or two parameter than you can use second option and first option scenario is adding whole object.
But if you are really obivious about your Performance than for you information Entity framework in really fast approach for CRUD operations. So no big deal for performance while using EntityFramework

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's a select or insert right ?

Comment: Yes. It depends how your adding and Selecting. If your selecting data from multiple tables(Say 5 tables) at a time in single query than performance can be a bit low. Similar condition is for Inserting and updating.

Answer (score 1):

Both are **correct**, when correctness is defined as valid in C#.

Depending on use, one may pick one pattern or the other. There is no cookie cutter approach, and you won't see any performance differences.

For instance, if you wanted to validate an existing object of type `MyClass` then you would expect a whole item. The same goes for passing in objects with **lots** of properties, or when the number of parameters needed will increase over time.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

If your method is processing an (data/domain) entity, is should not even be a class; but rather an interface - which you will feed it to the method my means of a IoC framework.

If it needs to frequently pass it to other code blocks, in form of another class; then perhaps it's easier to use an entity class, which will be mapped to the result type.

It it's a pure function which is just calculating something (and it's algorithm does not change and you do not use something like a Strategy Pattern) then you can use just named parameters.

These are not ALL possible situations. These are just (IMHO) good ways of performing this task.

And I always start with simple named arguments! Avoid premature optimization! Wait for patterns in your code to emerge.